# grep and sed equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell

I am trying to do the following statement in PowerShell

```
svn info filename | grep '^Last Changed Date:'| sed -e 's/^Last Changed Date: //'
```

I have tried this:

```
svn info filename | Select-String '^Last Changed Date:'
```

I am expecting below output

```
Thursday, December 20, 2018 4:50:40 AM
```

Comment: what is the output that you are trying to parse? not everyone has SVN ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To remove the leading label you could use a capture group with the RegEx pattern.

```
svn info filename | Select-String '^Last Changed Date: (.*)$' | ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Or taking Ansgars approach without the match (and repeating the label)

```
(svn info filename) -replace "(?sm).*?^Last Changed Date: (.*?)$.*","`$1"
```

Comment: the above is returning this "2017-05-05 12:03:02 -0400 (Fri, 05 May 2017)". what time format is this in powershell?? i need the same format to compare with today time in powershell.

Comment: `-replace` without `-match` will not remove non-matching lines from the `svn` output (same as using `sed` without `grep`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I agree that if no match is found the whole output is returned unchanged, but IMO that seems quite unlikely in this case.

Answer (score 21):

Use the `-match` and `-replace` [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0):

```
(svn info filename) -match '^Last Changed Date:' -replace '^Last Changed Date: '
```

Answer (score 19):

This might be dodging the question, but you could just use the `sed` and `grep`-statements within powershell by importing them from an existing git installation.

If installed, `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` contains a pretty good selection of the statements you're looking for, such as `sed.exe`. You can set an alias for these and use them in the way you're used to:

```
Set-Alias -Name sed -Value C:\"Program Files"\Git\usr\bin\sed.exe
```

You can define these aliases in a configuration file to preserve them. Create a file called `C:\Users\*UserName*\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` and allow script execution in powershell with admin rights by calling:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Comment: yessssss.   `"some string" | & 'C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin\sed.exe' -e 's/^some/any/'` -> `any string`.     or with the alias, you can drop the `&` - `'some string' | sed -e 's/^some/any/'`

Comment: To create the profile script file, just call the variable $profile with your preferred editor.  `notepad | vim | code $profile `
The variable contains the name and location for the current user.