# Append Gitlab pipeline ID to version in .Net pipeline

Tags: .net, gitlab, msbuild, gitlab-ci, versioning

I am using a Gitlab pipeline to build and publish my application. We specify our version in the AssemblyInfo.Version.cs file:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.1")]
```

I am looking for a way to append the Gitlab pipeline ID to the end of this version string. So, after publishing, the version of the resulting DLL will become:

```
 1.0.1.7226532
```

If possible, this should only be done using msbuild command line tool, so no importing of target files or anything.

I already found the environment variable from Gitlab where I can read the pipeline id:

```
CI_PIPELINE_IID
```

Now I only need to append this to the existing version number using msbuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `msbuild`, but since it's just a file you can use `sed` to perform a search and replace.

Assuming that the version in your example comes from something the pipeline can use a variable for (for example a git tag, CI variable you update each time the version changes, etc.), you can search the `AssemblyInfo.Version.cs` file for that value, and replace it:

```yaml
# ...
  script:
    - sed -i "s/${CI_COMMIT_TAG}/${CI_COMMIT_TAG}.${CI_PIPELINE_ID}/g" AssemblyInfo.Version.cs
```

Breaking down the `sed` command:

1. The `-i` flag says to edit the file in place. Note: on BSD systems, `-i` works a [little differently](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1)
2. The `s` at the beginning of the argument tells `sed` we want to do a *substitution*, then sets the delimiter between arguments to `/` (you can change this to another character if it's a conflict).
3. We're searching for this first parameter, `${CI_COMMIT_TAG}`
4. and replacing it with `${CI_COMMIT_TAG}.${CI_PIPELINE_ID}`
5. The `/g` at the end says to replace all instances of our search string in the file, not just the first
6. At the end we provide the file we want to search/replace with

By the way, I'd recommend against using the `$CI_PIPELINE_IID` variable as that is the project-specific ID, opposed to `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` which is the instance-wide pipeline ID. In some items in GitLab you want to use the `IID` version, such as Merge Requests, Issues, etc. since the IID is what's displayed in the UI. For example, with an Issue, it has both an instance-wide `ISSUE_ID` and a project-specific `ISSUE_IID`. Since the `IID` is displayed in the UI, users will quickly be able to visually map those two together.

GitLab does the exact opposite with pipelines however: the instance-wide `CI_PIPELINE_ID` is shown in the UI, *not* the project-specific `CI_PIPELINE_IID`.

Using `$CI_PIPELINE_IID` in your use case could cause some confusion as you might be looking at the `AssemblyInfo.Version.cs` file, see an ID, but can't find it in the list of Pipelines.

Comment: I am using Powershell as the pipeline shell actually. But I am on the same road as your answer right now. Currently I am trying to come up with a single PS command which will do the same thing as the sed command.

Comment: Ah, didn't catch you were using Powershell. After some _very_ quick googling, it looks like this might be an equivalent search/replace flow? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867484/2307873